# mysql query abnormal behaviour

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in mysql:

1: subject

```
code    title                    L-T-P   credits
CE10001 APPLIED MECHANICS        3-1-0  4
CH10001 CHEMISTRY I              3-1-0  4
CS20006 SOFTWARE ENGINEERING     3-0-0  3
CS21002 SWITCHING CIRCUITS AND LOGIC D  3-1-0   4
CS21003 ALGORITHMS - I  3-1-0   4
CS21004 FORMAL LANGUAGE AND AUTOMATA T  3-1-0   4
CS29002 SWITCHING CIRCUITS LABORATORY   0-0-3   2
CS29003 ALGORITHMS LABORATORY   0-0-3   2
```

2: studies

```
rollno      code
15CS10001   CH10001
15CS10002   CH10001
15CS10003   CH10001
15CS10004   CH10001
15CS10005   CH10001
15CS10006   CH10001
15CS10007   CH10001
15CS10008   CH10001
15CS10009   CH10001
15CS10010   CH10001
15CS10011   CH10001
15CS10012   CH10001
```

3: Student

```
rollno      name
12CS10001   A GOPI
12CS10002   AAYUSH SINGHAL
12CS10003   ABHISHEK KUMAR
12CS10004   AKSHAY GUPTA
12CS10005   AMRIT PATEL
12CS10006   ANKIT KUMAR GUPTA
12CS10007   ARKANATH PATHAK
12CS10008   ASEEM PATNI
12CS10009   AVANTSA NAGA RAJITHA
12CS10010   AYUSH VERMA
12CS10011   B SRUJAN
```

**I want to select subjects which have all the students from single batch. Batch is first 6 letters of rollno (eg. `12CS60R13` is from batch `12CS60`)**

I have written following query:

```
select st.rollno,sub.title 
from studies as st , subject as sub
where sub.code = st.code
group by st.code,(substring(st.rollno,1,6)) 
having count(rollno) = 
(select count(stu1.rollno) from student as stu1
    where substring(stu1.rollno,1,6) = substring(st.rollno,1,6));
```

I am getting following result, which is correct.

```
rollno      title
15CS10001   CHEMISTRY I
14CS10001   SOFTWARE ENGINEERING
14CS10001   SWITCHING CIRCUITS AND LOGIC D
13CS10001   OPERATING SYSTEMS
13CS10001   COMPUTER NETWORKS
12CS10001   DATABASE MANAGEMENT SYSTEMS
12CS10001   COMPUTER GRAPHICS
15CS60D01   DESIGN LABORATORY
15CS60D01   DISTRIBUTED SYSTEMS
15CS10001   ELECTRICAL ENGINEERING I
15CS10001   ENGINEERING MATHEMATICS I
15CS10001   ENGINEERING DRAWING I
15CS10001   WORKSHOP PRACTICE I
15CS10001   PHYSICS I
```

But when I remove `st.rollno` from select, I am getting following error.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]
Why am I getting error even if I am not changing anything other than select statement?

Comment: Are you sure your query is working?

Comment: Yup . i am getting perfect results. but don't want to display rollno. thats why removing st.rollno from select. but getting error.

Comment: Does it help if you use `having count(st.rollno) = ...`

Comment: @HoneyBadger no, it is not having any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select title from (
  select st.rollno,sub.title 
from studies as st , subject as sub
where sub.code = st.code
group by st.code,(substring(st.rollno,1,6)) 
having count(rollno) = 
(select count(stu1.rollno) from student as stu1
    where substring(stu1.rollno,1,6) = substring(st.rollno,1,6)))A;
```

Comment: No, it will not groupby batches. if you add st.rollno in group by clause.

Comment: @KrunalParmar: then your only solution if you want to keep the group by as it is, is to use a subquery. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as well.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: I see this is a quote from MySQL docs, but I don't believe that the standard really reqires a *column* to be mentioned in GROUP BY to be used in HAVING. That wouldn't make much sense. One can group by columns and *expressions* and either one should be fine for HAVING. Grouping by `substring(st.rollno,1,6)` and using this expression in HAVING should be fine. It is more likely that we are seeing a MySQL flaw here (both in the DBMS *and* the docs) in my opinion. But I may be wrong of course. Anyway, the link and quote explain, why the OP's query is not working - which the other answer does not.